# Can I pre-prepare dauphinoise potatoes?

Tags: potatoes, dairy

I am hosting my first Christmas for the mother-in-law so of course am freaking out.

I'm planning on cooking a roast something but with a slightly different spin on it from normal Christmas Dinner as it'll be on the 27th so I thought of making something different.

I thought dauphinoise potatoes would go down a treat. I haven't made them before but the recipe seems fairly straightforward. My question is how much prep can I do the day before? As I'm keen to have a few dishes ready and on trays to go in the oven without needing lots of morning prep.

Can I pre-slice the potatoes? Will they keep in water in the fridge?

I have seen some recipes which include cream, garlic and gruyere. I'm guessing these ingredients need to be cooked off immediately prior and cannot be made up beforehand.

Comment: Hi Francesca and welcome. Would you please edit your post to include the recipe you will be using? This will help in getting you better and more detailed answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it days in advance and freeze it.

Bake it as the recipe says, then cover with aluminum foil and plastic wrap and freeze it **as quickly as possible** (that it the most important factor)

On christmas day, get it out of the freezer, pop it in the oven and serve when really hot.

Comment: Exactly what I'd say. Dauphinoise potatoes are delicious and it can be made days or even weeks ahead of time. The one thing I'd point out @Max is that if it's being made a couple of days before it can be refrigerated instead of frozen, making reheating much faster.